# Error installing printer driver

Tags: macos, permission, printing, driver

I recently upgraded from Mojave to Big Sur (11.4).  The connection to my network printer (Epson Artisan 810) was not functioning, so I removed it and attempted to reinstall the driver.  It fails to so, stating `An error occurred while trying to add the selected device. successful-ok-ignored-or-substituted-attributes`

[image]

I have rebooted and reset the print system, all to no avail.  Console does provide some clues when "printer" is searched:

```
default 09:48:01.456005-0400    runningboardd   Acquiring assertion targeting [app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027] from originator [daemon<com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd>:125] with description <RBSAssertionDescriptor| "frontmost:1027" ID:200-125-18714 target:1027 attributes:[
    <RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.launchservicesd" name:"RoleUserInteractiveFocal" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">
    ]>
default 09:48:01.456317-0400    runningboardd   Assertion 200-125-18714 (target:[app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027]) will be created as active
default 09:48:01.479778-0400    runningboardd   Calculated state for app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>: running-active (role: UserInteractiveFocal)
default 09:48:01.482394-0400    runningboardd   Finished acquiring assertion 200-125-18714 (target:[app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027])
default 09:48:01.483366-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027] Ignoring jetsam update because this process is not memory-managed
default 09:48:01.483388-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027] Ignoring suspend because this process is not lifecycle managed
default 09:48:01.483601-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027] Set darwin role to: UserInteractiveFocal
default 09:48:01.483899-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027] Ignoring GPU update because this process is not GPU managed
default 09:48:01.484344-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027] Skipping AppNap state - not lifecycle managed
default 09:48:01.484477-0400    runningboardd   Acquiring assertion targeting [app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027] from originator [daemon<com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd>:125] with description <RBSAssertionDescriptor| "notification:1027" ID:200-125-18715 target:1027 attributes:[
    <RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.launchservicesd" name:"LSNotification" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">
    ]>
default 09:48:01.484553-0400    runningboardd   Assertion 200-125-18715 (target:[app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027]) will be created as active
default 09:48:01.485064-0400    runningboardd   Calculated state for app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>: running-active (role: UserInteractiveFocal)
default 09:48:01.485209-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027] Ignoring jetsam update because this process is not memory-managed
default 09:48:01.485251-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027] Ignoring suspend because this process is not lifecycle managed
default 09:48:01.485287-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027] Ignoring GPU update because this process is not GPU managed
default 09:48:01.485428-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027] Skipping AppNap state - not lifecycle managed
default 09:48:01.485663-0400    runningboardd   Finished acquiring assertion 200-125-18715 (target:[app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027])
default 09:48:04.800023-0400    authd   Succeeded authorizing right 'system.print.admin' by client '/usr/sbin/cupsd' [869] for authorization created by '/System/Library/CoreServices/AddPrinter.app' [1027] (2,0) (engine 1474)
default 09:48:07.479723-0400    runningboardd   Assertion did invalidate due to timeout: 200-125-18715 (target:[app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027])
default 09:48:07.686923-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027] Ignoring jetsam update because this process is not memory-managed
default 09:48:07.686939-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027] Ignoring suspend because this process is not lifecycle managed
default 09:48:07.686954-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027] Ignoring GPU update because this process is not GPU managed
default 09:48:07.686999-0400    runningboardd   [app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027] Skipping AppNap state - not lifecycle managed
default 09:48:07.687164-0400    runningboardd   Calculated state for app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>: running-active (role: UserInteractiveFocal)
default 09:48:23.980779-0400    authd   Succeeded authorizing right 'system.print.admin' by client '/System/Library/CoreServices/AddPrinter.app' [1027] for authorization created by '/System/Library/CoreServices/AddPrinter.app' [1027] (13,0) (engine 1476)
default 09:48:24.091142-0400    AddPrinter  #print printToolAgent:error - 1, command - kCPLCreateQueue (32)
default 09:48:24.096937-0400    AddPrinter  #print Unable to add printer: "<private>"
default 09:48:27.282442-0400    authd   Succeeded authorizing right 'system.print.admin' by client '/usr/sbin/cupsd' [869] for authorization created by '/System/Library/CoreServices/AddPrinter.app' [1027] (2,0) (engine 1477)
default 09:48:28.299091-0400    runningboardd   Invalidating assertion 200-125-18714 (target:[app<application.com.apple.print.add.1152921500312125551.1152921500312125556(502)>:1027]) from originator [daemon<com.apple.coreservices.launchservicesd>:125]
```

Searching on "epson" yielded this:

```
error   09:48:04.840050-0400    kernel  Sandbox: epsonfirewire(18123) deny(1) sysctl-write kern.system_version_compat
error   09:48:27.322184-0400    kernel  Sandbox: epsonfirewire(18138) deny(1) sysctl-write kern.system_version_compat
```

Comment: Where did you get the driver from?

Comment: Have you try download and install drivers from this link : https://epson.com/Support/Printers/All-In-Ones/Artisan-Series/Epson-Artisan-810/s/SPT_C11CA52201 ?

Comment: I originally had the manufacturer drivers installed at the time of the upgrade.  I experienced the problem at that point and installed the latest version.  This did not solve the problem, so I uninstalled the manufacturer drivers, assuming the Apple drivers would work.

Comment: @Jean_JD I know I installed the latest driver from Epson and it didn't work, but I tried again and it is now installed.  Thanks for the suggestion!